# How to apply a hover color on an option tag in HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html-select

How to apply a hover color as the default select option drop in a drop down menu in HTML and CSS?
Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: `#selector:hover{color:red}` [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This example helps you.(work on Internet Explorer)

```css
option {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 3;
  padding: 20px;
}

option:hover {
  background: black;
  color: red;
}

option:active {
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
}

option:focus {
  background: green;
  colour: orange;
}
```

```html
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try with another web browser. like Internet Explorer